# Diffusion (random walk) on lattice using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 9 by 9 cubic lattice. in each site of the lattice, there are N molecules. which N is a large random number and differs in different sites. I want each molecule to do a random walk in each time step.

Could anyone give an answer to this question?

*I don't want to track each individual particles, but I want to track for each site the number of particles I have there.

Comment: I am not a matlab expert but I dont see any code. If you want someone to spend time answering its better if you give them more details. See here please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added @dparoli

Comment: It looks like you added some code as requested, and then deleted it again. Given that you seem to be asking for someone to do the whole thing for you, the question was off-topic anyway - the point of code is to show us what you are working on, not simply to satisfy the posting guidelines.

Comment: I delete it because I thought it was confusing.@halfer